# Meaning of $f\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)$ with Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, fourier-transform

What is the meaning of this equation? Has it a name?
$$f\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)y(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_t\left[f(2\pi i t)\cdot\mathcal{F}_x[y(x)](t)\right](x)$$
Where $\mathcal{F}_x[y(x)](t)$ is the Fourier transform of $y(x)$

Special case: if $f(z)=\exp(az)$
$$\exp\left(a\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)y(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_t\left[\exp(2\pi i a t)\cdot\mathcal{F}_x[y(x)](t)\right](x)\\
e^{a\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}}y(x)=\mathcal{F}_t^{-1}\left[e^{2\pi ia t}\cdot\mathcal{F}_x[y(x)](t)\right](x)\\
e^{a\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}}y(x)=\mathcal{F}_t^{-1}\left[\mathcal{F}_x[y(x)](t)\right](x+a)\\
e^{a\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}}y(x)=y(x+a)
$$
Is the shift operator.

Comment: Where did you find this formula?

Comment: I calculated it by myself, it's not complex, if you want I can include the steps in the question

Comment: No, that's okay, I understand what steps you took, you used the properties of the Fourier transform, correct?

Comment: Yes, totally correct

Comment: as far as I know something like $f(\frac{d}{d x})$ is not well-defined for functions that grow faster than any polynomial, at least in the context of Fourier multipliers